# How to resolve a class in laravel container with extra arguments?

Tags: php, laravel-5, containers, ioc-container

How to resolve a class in laravel container with extra arguments?

This works perfect and without any registration:

```
class myClass
{
    public function __construct(Interf1 $i1, Interf2 $i2)
    {
        //some stuff
    }
}
$mc = app()->make('myClass');
```

What happends if you need something like this:

```
class myClass
{
    public function __construct(Interf1 $i1, Interf2 $i2, $x, $y)
    {
        //some stuff
    }
}
```

Is there an option like:

> $mc = app()->make('myClass',[10,20]);

or

> $mc = app()->make('myClass')->with(10,20);

I know I can use setters but thats not the point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is exactly the first version you already wrote, but you missed the keys which must match the arguments in the constructor:

```
$mc = app()->make('myClass',['x' => 10, 'y' => 20]);
```